# How to merge a public repo into my own but continue to receive updates from the public one?

Tags: java, git, frameworks, frontend, backend

So there are 2 repositories:

- Repository A (My own private repo) - backend only code which runs via my IDE or the terminal.
- [Repository B](https://github.com/yohangz/java-play-react-seed) (Someone else's public repo) - seed for Java's Play Web Framework with React.

I want to implement the web framework from **Repo B** so I can run my app with it. I don't particularly care if I retain the commit history of **Repo B**, but I would like to retain the commit history of **Repo A**.

Just copying the files from **Repo B** to **Repo A** and committing them isn't great, because I want git to keep tracking changes and to allow me to continue merging things from **Repo B** into my **Repo A** as the framework gets updated.

Is there any way to set this up so future merging is as pain free as possible once fully set up, almost as if just merging from a different branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend looking into [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). They're sort of like repositories inside of repositories.

Comment: That's pretty neat, I didn't know about it. However, it isn't a perfect fit I think. This will (by the looks of it) allow me to pull in one repo into another as a submodule contained in its own folder.

The problem with this is that the repo I want to pull in is the framework which can't be in it's own folder. Instead my own repo should be in its own folder within the framework, i.e. the framework is a level above my own repo's code and my code will be inside the framework. Submodules will let me do the opposite structure unless I'm failing to think of something?